# X3DOM: ROUTE vs DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, x3d, x3dom

I would like to do some translation and rotation animations in X3DOM.

One way of doing it is with Routes, TimeSensors, and PositionInterpolators.

Another way is through DOM manipulation:  document.getElementById('myTransform').translation='2 3 1';
These call would then be made many times in sequence either via setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame.

Do Routes offer better performance?  Any other advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Are you just asking what's better, setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame ?

Comment: I am mainly asking whether Routes are better than a sequence of calls which keep changing the translation attribute to produce the animation.  Input on requestAnimationFrame vs setTimeout is also welcome.